# Presentation of Witt vectors of polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I'm interested in a concrete representation of $W_n (\mathbb{F}_p [x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_k])$ as of an algebra over $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$.
I think that $W_2 (\mathbb{F}_p [x])$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p^2 [a, b]/(pb, b^2)$. I think it is generated by the Teichmuller representative of $x$ and $Vx$ the latter element squares to zero. However, I'm struggling to understand what happens in general.

Comment: The title of your post makes it clear which ring you are talking about, but it might be helpful to include parentheses in the body of the post.

Comment: @BrianShin did it now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The main trick I know of for getting your hands on Witt vectors (of $\mathbb F_p$-algebras) is to reduce to the case of perfect $\mathbb F_p$-algebras, where we can appeal to the theorem that $W(-)$ and $(-)/p$ define inverse equivalences of categories between perfect $\mathbb F_p$-algebras and strict $p$-rings.  The idea is this:  if $R$ is a *reduced* $\mathbb F_p$-algebra, then $R$ embeds into its direct limit perfection
$$
R_{\mathrm{perf}} := \mathrm{colim}_{x \mapsto x^p} R,
$$
as all the transition maps of the colimit are injective.  By functoriality of the Witt coordinate maps (of sets)
$$
W(-) \simeq (-)^{\mathbb N},
$$
it follows that $W(R) \to W(R_{\mathrm{perf}})$ is injective.  But the image of $W(R)$ in $W(R_{\mathrm{perf}})$ is topologically generated by elements of the form $V^n([x])$, where $[x]$ is the multiplicative lift of $x \in R$.

In the case of $R = \mathbb F_p[x_1, \dots, x_k]$, this works as follows.  The direct limit perfection is
$$
R_{\mathrm{perf}} = \mathbb F_p[x_1^{1/p^{\infty}}, \dots, x_k^{1/p^{\infty}}]
$$
We can easily write down a strict $p$-ring $A$ such that $A/p \simeq R_{\mathrm{perf}}$, namely
$$
A = \mathbb Z_p[x_1^{1/p^{\infty}}, \dots, x_k^{1/p^{\infty}}]^{\wedge},
$$
where $(-)^{\wedge}$ denotes $p$-adic completion.  Thus we must have $A \simeq W(R_{\mathrm{perf}})$.  Moreover, we can choose this isomorphism so that $x_i^{\alpha} \in A$ is the multiplicative lift of $x_i^{\alpha} \in R_{\mathrm{perf}}$ for each $i$ and each $\alpha \in \mathbb Z[1/p]_{\geq 0}$.  Then we have
\begin{align*}
F(x_i^{\alpha}) & = (x_i^{\alpha})^p = x_i^{p \alpha} \text{ and} \\
V(x_i^{\alpha}) & = p F^{-1}(x_i^{\alpha}) = p x_i^{\alpha/p}
\end{align*}
in $A$, for $\alpha \in \mathbb Z[1/p]_{\geq 0}$.<sup>1</sup>

The subring $W(R)$ is topologically generated by the $V$-orbits of the multiplicative lifts of elements of $R$, and in particular by the elements
$$
V^n([x_1^{m_1} \cdots x_k^{m_k}]) = p^n x_1^{m_1/p^n} \cdots x_k^{m_k/p^n}
$$
with $m_i, n \in \mathbb N$.  That is, we can have monomials with arbitrary powers of $p$ in the denominators of the exponents, provided that the coefficient in front is divisible by at least an equal power of $p$.

The topology on $W(R_{\mathrm{perf}})$ was just the $p$-adic topology, and the topology on $W(R)$ is the subspace topology.  This is no longer the $p$-adic topology (because e.g. the elements $p^n x_1^{1/p^n}$ go to $0$ even though they aren't divisible by $p$), but rather what I like to call the coefficient-wise $p$-adic topology.

I find it easier to think about $W_n(R)$ as the quotient $W(R)/V^n W(R)$ (where $V^n W(R)$ consists of all elements of $W(R)$ built from monomials with coefficients divisible by $p^n$) than in terms of generators and relations.  You can, however, read off a set of generators and relations from my description--but there may be more generators and relations than you'd like.  For example, if $r = n = 2$, I would write the ring informally as
$$
W_2(\mathbb F_p[x, y]) = (\mathbb Z/p^2 \mathbb Z)[x, y, p x^{m_1/p} y^{m_2/p}].
$$
This gives a set of $p^2 + 1$ algebra generators, since it's enough to take $0 \leq m_i < p$, and we can exclude the redundant case $m_1 = m_2 = 0$.  You'd then have to impose the relations that all pairwise products of the generators "$p x^{m_1/p} y^{m_2/p}$" vanish.  If you're interested in $n = 3$ instead, then you'll need additional generators of the form
$$
V^2(x^{m_1} y^{m_2}) = p^2 x^{m_1/p^2} y^{m_2/p^2},
$$
and so on.

In particular, your description of $W(\mathbb F_p[x])$ is correct if $p=2$, but I claim that in general you need to adjoin $a = x$ and $p-1$ Verschiebung elements
$$b_1 = V(x), \dots, b_{p-1} = V(x^{p-1}),$$
where all pairwise products of the $b_i$ (and $b_0 = V(1) = p$) vanish.  Recall in particular that $V$ is not multiplicative; we just have
$$
V(F(a) \cdot b) = a \cdot V(b)
$$
and therefore
$$
V(a) \cdot V(b) = V(F(Va) \cdot b) = V(pa \cdot b) = pV(a \cdot b).
$$

---

<sup>1</sup> If you want to redo this story over a perfect base field $k$ larger than $\mathbb F_p$, then $W(k)$ will play the role of $\mathbb Z_p$, and the equations above become semilinear over the Witt vector Frobenius $\sigma:  W(k) \to W(k)$; e.g. $F(a x_i^{\alpha}) = \sigma(a) x_i^{p \alpha}$.  This isn't necessary here because $\sigma:  \mathbb Z_p \to \mathbb Z_p$ is the identity.